# Removing duplicate rows in dataframes with multiple columns

Tags: r

In a dataframe like this

```
a <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C",2))
b <- c(1,1,2,4,1,1,2,2)
df <-data.frame(a,b)
```

it is possible to remove duplicates using (based on the results of b column) :

```
df[!duplicated(df), ]
```

if a have a third column c in the df and I would like again to remove the duplicate based on the values of column b is it right to use this:

```
 df[!duplicated(df$b), ]
```

using a third column.
The dataframe:

```
a <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C",2))
b <- c(1,1,2,4,1,1,2,2)
c <- c("i","i","ii","ii","iii","iii","iv","iv")
df <-data.frame(a,b,c)
```

using remove duplicates based on column b:

```
 df[!duplicated(df$b), ]
```

the result is this:

```
a b  c
A 1  i
A 2 ii
B 4 ii
```

and I would expect this

```
 a b c
A 1 i
A 2 ii
B 4 ii
B 1 iii
C 2 iv
```

Comment: Did you try that?

Comment: @JulianHeinovski yes and this doesn't give the output I would expect thank you for your comment.

Comment: Well, why didn't you write this then?

Comment: I don't get it. `df <- df[!duplicated(df$b), ]` **is** the right way to do it. what is your question?

Comment: @JonGrub I have updated my question please take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input:

```
a <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C",2))
b <- c(1,1,2,4,1,1,2,2)
c <- c("i","i","ii","ii","iii","iii","iv","iv")
df <-data.frame(a,b,c)
```

Described as expected output in post:

```
 a b c  
 A 1 i
 A 2 ii
 B 4 ii
 B 1 iii
 C 2 iv
```

Using `distinct` on all columns seems to do what you want:

```
>library(dplyr)
>distinct(df)
  a b   c
1 A 1   i
2 A 2  ii
3 B 4  ii
4 B 1 iii
5 C 2  iv
```

Other variation: only allow unique `b`'s:

```
> distinct(df,b, .keep_all = TRUE)
  a b  c
1 A 1  i
2 A 2 ii
3 B 4 ii
```

Comment: Thank you. I try to find a way to remove the duplicate rows based on df$b column and avoid to remove duplicate rows which have the same value in other column expect from b

Comment: `distinct(df,b, .keep_all = TRUE)`

Comment: thank you again Erwin but it gives me the same results. I have updated the question with the results

Comment: I don't think you are filtering on `b` only but on all columns

Comment: Yes and when I tried your suggestion `distinct(df,b, .keep_all = TRUE)` I take the same result that's why I am asking. Thank you. I can't understand what I am making wrong. thank you.

Comment: Nice one Erwin Kalvelagen!!